Cop movie where a cop sets up his partner in the first scene
I remember that there is a setup early in the movie where it is supposed to be a drug bust but it is really a hit on one of the cops and they were going to frame (or did frame) the drug dealer.  Then the ex-partner of the cop provides comfort to the grieving wife.  The drug dealer gets away but is caught later in the movie. There is also a scene where the drug dealer's lawyer is talking to someone in a sauna when the story begins to come out. It is not Justice for All is it?  Or maybe Brooklyn's Finest?

Just hoping someone might know what it is.  It is a pretty memorable story line.  I just can't remember the movie.  I don't think it is either of those movies but getting ready to watch Brooklyn's Finest again anyway.

Possibly Night Falls on Manhattan from 1996 with Andy Garcia, James Gandolfini (as the corrupt cop) and Richard Dreyfuss as the drug dealer's lawyer:

Attorney Sean Cassey is called on by the New York District Attorney to try drug kingpin Jordon Washington, accused of murdering two cops and injuring a third, Sean's father. The publicity from the trial is a boom to Sean's career, but when Washington's lawyer, Sam Vigoda, makes accusations of police corruption that hit Sean too close to home, Sean is divided between justice, his career, and his family.

There's a scene where Dreyfuss talks to Garcia in a sauna. It appears here in the trailer, around 1:06:




Funny, that is absolutely it!  I was actually paging through every movie myself at Amazon and found it at the same time.  Yes, Richard Dreyfus was the guy in the sauna.  Thanks!!
